# Django: Refactoring the "right" way

Tags: python, django

My `DetailView` currently gets longer and longer. And therefore I am trying to learn more about some better practices to shorten it again. Right now, I am looking into the `def post()` part. The full code is even longer. My best idea currently is to create a utils.py in the same folder and take out the code snippets inside the `if else` statements. Is that best practice or would you do it in a different way?

```
class EventDetail(DetailView):
    [...]

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # Discount code POST
        if self.discount_form.is_valid():
            discount_code = self.discount_form.cleaned_data['code']
            request.session[discount_cookie_name(request.event)] = discount_code
            return redirect(reverse_obj(self.request.event, 'events:detail'))

        # Consent form POST
        elif self.consent_form.is_valid():

            # Check if email entry exists
            contact = request.event.organizer.contacts.filter(
                email=self.consent_form.cleaned_data['email']
            ).first()
            success_message = _("You successfully signed up to receive event updates.")

            if contact:
                # Check if current event is allocated to entered email.
                event_entry = contact.contact_relation.filter(
                    event=request.event
                ).first()
                if event_entry:
                    event_entry.lead = True
                    event_entry.save(update_fields=['lead'])
                    messages.success(request, success_message)
                else:
                    # Email entry exists, but event allocation must be added.
                    ContactRelation.objects.create(
                        lead=True, contact=contact, event=request.event
                    )
                    messages.success(request, success_message)
            # Create new email entry and allocate event.
            else:
                instance = self.consent_form.save(commit=False)
                instance.organizer = request.event.organizer
                instance.save()
                instance.contact_relations.add(
                    request.event, through_defaults={'lead': True}
                )
                messages.success(request, success_message)
            return redirect(reverse_obj(self.request.event, 'events:detail'))

        elif self.formset.is_valid():
            # Check if the user already has an order_reference in the session
            old_order_reference = request.session.get('order_reference')
            if old_order_reference is not None:
                ReservedItem.objects.filter(
                    order_reference=old_order_reference
                ).delete()

            # Generate a new order_reference and save it in the session
            order_reference = unique_order_reference_generator()
            request.session['order_reference'] = order_reference

            for form in self.formset:
                quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
                qty = 0 if not quantity else quantity
                if qty > 0:
                    reserved_item = form.save(commit=False)
                    ticket = form.cleaned_data['ticket']
                    reserved_item.order_reference = order_reference
                    reserved_item.ticket_name = ticket.name

                    if ticket.tax:
                        reserved_item.ticket_tax = ticket.tax
                        reserved_item.tax_name = ticket.tax.name
                        reserved_item.tax_percentage = ticket.tax.percentage

                    # Prevent AttributeError
                    discount_obj = None

                    if self.discount_code:
                        discount_obj = self.discount_code

                    if self.social_ticketing_referral:
                        # That part is not inside generate_reserved_discount_items
                        # as the influencer is still getting points. Even, if the ticket
                        # has no discount.
                        reserved_item.social_ticketing_referral = (
                            self.social_ticketing_referral.ambassador
                        )
                        # Add points earned per ticket
                        reserved_item.social_ticketing_unit_points_earned = (
                            ticket.points.points
                            if self.social_ticketing.is_point_mode_manual()
                            else monetary_amount_to_points(
                                ticket.price_gross, request.event.currency
                            )
                        )

                        # Check if Social Ticketing has incentive discount (not talking point).
                        # That also means self.discount_code doesn't apply
                        if self.social_ticketing.is_incentive_discount():
                            discount_obj = self.social_ticketing.discount
                            reserved_item.discount_code = (
                                self.social_ticketing_referral.code
                            )

                    if discount_obj:
                        generate_reserved_discount_items(
                            reserved_item=reserved_item,
                            discount=discount_obj,
                            ticket=ticket,
                            quantity=quantity,
                        )

                    # Save reserved item
                    reserved_item.save()
            return redirect('checkout:checkout', step='start')

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Most of that probably belongs in the form.

Comment: You mean I should rather write it to the forms.py file?

Comment: This looks more like a `CreateView`, not a `DetailView`.